# How do I do https for a whole website, except for one folder?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have this htaccess file, which rewrites everything to https:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Is it possible to make an exception for a single folder, so it runs on normal http?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following RewriteCond can be used:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/test/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Uses http for:

```
http://example.com/test/abc.txt
```

but redirects to https for:

```
http://example.com/hello/abc.txt
```